# Under the Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact, how many of each aircraft did the USSR receive?

Tags: world-war-two, nazi-germany, soviet-union

The [Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Molotov%E2%80%93Ribbentrop_Pact) was signed 1939 Aug 23, and lasted till 1941 Jun 22.

During that time, **how many aircraft** were delivered to the Soviet Union, and **what types** were they? I'm especially interested in the bf 109s and what exact version they were.

Surprisingly difficult to track this down online. Surely someone must have made an inventory of this somewhere, but I cannot find it. Only general data is available such as Wikipedia's "thirty of Germany's latest warplanes, including the Bf 109 and Bf 110 fighters and Ju 88 bomber." That's the closest I've found to an answer.